# Repository Pattern to support Bounded Context

Tags: web-api, repository-pattern

I am building a REST Api from scratch so i am overthinking and revisiting various approaches and best practices.

I have a `Materials` repository that serve all the sub-domains of our logic.

Also i have a `Sales` and `Inventory` sub domains that both relate to the `Materials`.

I found [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279833/partitioning-rest-api-resources-into-areas-based-on-business-domains) question that evolves exactly around what i am doing and after going and now another question arises for me in regards to Repository pattern.

Let's consider the following REST Api routes:

1. `/masterdata/materials`. Provide a list of materials and their master data.
2. `/sales/materials`. Provide Sales per material in different granularoty.

Where the methods that satisfy `/sales/materials` have to be implemented?

In the Repository of `Materials` or in the `Sales` repository?

Comment: The Url `/sales/materials` implies that your aggregate is "sales," so that's where I would start.  But at the end of the day it doesn't really matter where you retrieve the materials from, since there's no all-seeing, all-knowing authority looking over your shoulder telling you whether you're doing it right or wrong.  Put the materials retrieval method where it makes the most sense to you.

Comment: If it were up to me, I'd probably have the Sales repository call the Materials repository to retrieve materials, but the method will still work no matter where you put it.